# How to use Sphinx search in java

Tags: java, full-text-search, sphinx, full-text-indexing, sphinxql

I'm set up Sphinx and indexed my table. It works correctly in the [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZQ2q.png), but how i can execute this [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bw1K.png) in java? Is it possible? I guess Intellij Idea doesn't understand SphinxQL.

Comment: Hello, can you add example code and any errors you are getting.

Comment: @JohnMercier Hi, 
`String sql = "SELECT * FROM searchIndex WHERE MATCH('@text qweqwe')";
            
rs = st.executeQuery(sql);` 
Unexpected '<EOF>', 'AGAINST' expected
Error:java: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Answer (score 0):

> how i can execute this query in java?

Just work with that as with MySQL (in terms of connection). Few notes:

- prepared statements are not supported in Sphinx
- make sure you connect to correct Sphinx's port
- if you cannot connect try `mysql_version_string = 5.5.21`

As for the error you see in the IDE - it's probably just because it thinks it's MySQL. Sphinx understands mysql protocol, but the query syntax is different.